# Streamlit app stuck on „Please wait…“ on VPS with Apache2

Tags: web, apache2, vps, streamlit

I’m trying to deploy my app and all was great but I’m getting constant “Please wait…”.
Here is what I’m getting in browser console:

```
WebSocket connection to ws://<URL> failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

WebSocket connection to ws://<URL> failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

Uncaught Error: Unsupported state transition.
State: PINGING_SERVER
Event: CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
    at e.value (main.a8683c40.chunk.js:2:120961)
    at main.a8683c40.chunk.js:2:123059
```

Here is my app.domain.com.conf of apache2:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
        ServerName app.domain.com
        ServerAlias app.domain.com
        ProxyRequests Off
        <Location />
                ProxyPass http://app.domain.com:8502/
                ProxyPassReverse http://app.domain.com:8502/
                ProxyPreserveHost On
        </Location>
     # Uncomment the line below if your site uses SSL.
     #SSLProxyEngine On
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my ports.conf

```
Listen 80
Listen 8501
<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

On my main domain I’m hosting the landing page (port 80) and on app.mydomain.com (port 8502) streamlit app

What could be the issue here? Thank you!

I think tried everything what is online like:

Running these things:

```
streamlit run my_app.py --server.enableCORS=false
streamlit run my_app.py --server.enableWebsocketCompression=false
Adding this to streamlit config:
serverPort = 8502
```

Changing mydomain.com to server_ip also didn’t help

and all other things found online also were tried.

Comment: Have you checked out this thread? https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/streamlit-docker-nginx-ssl-https/2195/6